# L'Hôpital evaluating limits for multivariable functions?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Let's say I want to evaluate the following limit:

> $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 + y}{y}$$

and I choose the paths $x = 0$ (which gives me the limit equal to $1$) and I decide on the path $y = x$ also. By substituting $y = x$, does that allow me to use L'Hôpital?

> $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 + y}{y} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 + x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x+1}{1} = 1$$

Comment: Yes. Doesn't it look like a quotient of two functions.

Comment: This limit doesn't exist though.

Comment: You should be vary careful about saying stuff like $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 + y}{y} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 + x}{x}$$ This is necessarily true if the left side exists, but it is possible for the right side to exist and the left side not to exist.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews can I write the following?

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 + y}{y} \stackrel{y=x}{=} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 + x}{x}$$

Comment: If you want, but it's an abuse of notation. At least it is clearer what you mean then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use L'Hôpital though it is not necessary as you can just divide both the numerator and denominator by $x$.

Try to let $y=-x^2$ to prove that the limit doesn't exists.

Comment: So basically anytime I can rewrite the limit using a single variable, I can use L'Hôpital?
Yes I got $0$ as an answer, proving that the limit does not exist.

Comment: you can use it when it is in the indeterminate form. I take it as you travel through another path and you find the value to be $2$? then the limit doesn't exist. curious about which path though.

Comment: $y=x^2$ was my original choice.

Comment: Ah, awesome choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use L'Hôpital's rule on the path limit
$$
    \lim_{\substack{x\to 0 \\ y = x}} \frac{x^2+y}{y} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^2 + x}{x} \stackrel{\text{H}}{=} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x+1}{1} = 1
$$
*However*, that doesn't tell you enough to conclude that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^2+y}{y}=1$.  For as Siong Thye Goh suggests, you can find the limit along another path:
$$
    \lim_{\substack{x\to 0 \\ y = -x^2}} \frac{x^2+y}{y} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{0}{-x^2} = 0
$$
Since these two path limits disagree, we know $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^2+y}{y}$ does not exist.